# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with tomcat 8.5 and java 8 lambda x cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, java-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy java web application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with tomcat 8.5 and java 8.
My java application contain lambda expressions, but it didn't compiled with error **x cannot be resolved to a variable**
I have checked my environment and with:
`System.getProperty("catalina.base");
System.getProperty("java.version");`
and it give the correct java environment `/usr/share/tomcat8` and `1.8.0_181`
I have tried to user source 1.8 in my app web.xml by adding the following

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compiler</param-name>
        <param-value>modern</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>suppressSmap</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

also I have tried a custom config to AWS using server-update.config
`container_commands:
  replace-config:
    command: cp .ebextensions/web.xml /usr/share/tomcat8/web.xml`

But nothing is working, 
The question is: How can I tell tomcat to use java 1.8.

Edit: Sample Code
a very simple code I have tested

```
<%!
    String str = "";
%>

<%
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("1");
    test.add("2");
    test.add("3");
    test.add("4");
    test.add("5");

    test.stream().forEach(x -> str += x + " - ");
%>
```

Comment: Please provide some code. Everything indicates you are using Java 8. Also, you could try to deploy a minimal webapp to see if it runs.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the post

Comment: where comes the "x" in your error "x can not be resolved to a variable" ?

Comment: it is just another var name in sample code

Comment: Please help us to help you, be accurate. Also, did you look at the logs (catalina.out), you should see a line like "[INFO] ... JVM Version: 1.8.0_xyz" at the begining?

Comment: I'm sorry for this, I have checked catalina.out and found the line "JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13" I have also tried to put invalid java version to check if the configuration (8 instead of 1.8) is read by tomcat and it reads
"org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass Unknown source VM 8 ignored."

Comment: This confirm you are correctly using a Java 1.8 VM at runtime.

Comment: it proves that I have both java 1.8 and tomcat 8.5, but it doesn't mean that tomcat is using java 1.8 to compile the files.

Answer (score 1):

Having run into this myself, I believe the answer is: you can't. That is, Tomcat is indeed running under 1.8, but the problem you're seeing is that it can't (on Elastic Beanstalk) *compile* 1.8-level code in JSPs.

In order to compile JSPs, Tomcat requires two components: a JSP compiler (to produce Java code) and a Java compiler (to produce bytecode). The two parameters `compilerSourceVM` and `compilerTargetVM` set the language levels for these two compilations.

The following is only my best guess, but it seems to bear out in practice:

If a Java compiler is available in the Java environment, Tomcat can use it; otherwise it relies on an embedded compiler. Tomcat 8.x target Java 1.7, so its embedded compiler is a 1.7 compiler. Your development environment almost certainly includes a 1.8 compiler, so the configuration you give will work fine. But Elastic Beanstalk is configured with a Java environment lacking a compiler, so the highest language level supported by Tomcat 8.x is 1.7.

Tomcat 9 targets Java 1.8, and so contains a 1.8-level embedded compiler; it should be able to support your configuration regardless of whether a java compiler is available in the runtime environment. But Elastic Beanstalk (at the time of writing) doesn't support Tomcat 9, so you might well just be stuck with 1.7 support in JSPs.